# InterVLAN routing on a HP V1910 series switch

Tags: routing, switch, hp, vlan, 3com

Recently bought a HP V1910-16G switch (former 3com 29хх) with IPv4 routing capabilities. After unpacking I did a firmware upgrade to the latest 5.20 Release 1513P06. I did set up additional VLANs (#2 and #3) and VLAN interfaces for those.
The problem is that connected PCs on different VLAN's can't ping each other. Looks like VLAN routing doesn't even work.

So here's my setup:

```
    VLAN ID  VLAN interface
    1        10.0.0.21/24
    2        10.0.5.1/24
    3        10.0.6.1/24
```

Have one PC connected to VLAN 2 (IP address 10.0.5.2, default gateway 10.0.5.1) and a second PC connected to VLAN 3 (IP address 10.0.6.2, default gateway 10.0.6.1)

Routing table:

```
    Destination IP  Mask             Next Hop
    0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0          10.0.0.1
    10.0.0.0        255.255.255.0    10.0.0.21
    10.0.0.21       255.255.255.255  127.0.0.1
    10.0.5.0        255.255.255.0    10.0.5.1
    10.0.5.1        255.255.255.255  127.0.0.1
    10.0.6.0        255.255.255.0    10.0.6.1
    10.0.6.1        255.255.255.255  127.0.0.1
    127.0.0.0       255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1
    127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255  127.0.0.1
```

The first PC can't ping the second PC one and vice versa. They only can ping their own gateways and that's all. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is routing enabled on the switch?

Comment: This switch doesn't have any options to enable or disable the routing. According to the manual the routing must be enabled by default.

Comment: what version have you downgraded to?
Im experiencing exactly the same trouble as you.

Comment: Hi. Version 5.20 Release 1111P02 - it's the default firmware, which came with the switch. I had luck that I haven't deleted it from switch's flash. May be that some older versions than the latest one also work fine, but I don't have enough time to test them.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I downgraded to the old firmware and the routing works. After downgrade I just rebooted the switch and both PCs could ping each other. Any additional configuration wasn't needed.
Shame on HP. Releasing not well tested firmware updates with regressions is disappointing me.